# Is it possible to make a purchase or get price while app is in Pending Developer Release state?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

My app is in Pending Developer Release. 
I have downloaded it using promo code.
When I try to make purchase or get the price of a products, nothing happens. Is it possible to make purchases or get the prices while the app is in this state or it will be possible only once my app is in Ready For Sale state?

Thanks a lot, 
Giora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For other people who encounter the same dilema..

I released the app and products and prices became available and worked perfectly.

So,  App in Pending Developer Release status cannot make any purchase of In App Purchase products. Only apps in Ready for sale state can.

Off course I'm talking about real purchases and not Sandbox Testers.

Thanks all.